# What does git remote command 'set-branches' do?

Tags: git, git-remote

From the documentation, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-branchesem, it is not clear to me what it actually does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was introduced with Git v1.7.2-rc0 in May 2010, [commit 3d8b694](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d8b69495fd1132d5af6d7f46425cca97a937d97) with the comment:

> ### Add git remote set-branches
>
> Add ‘`git remote set-branches`’ for changing the list of tracked refs
> for a remote repository with one "porcelain-level" command.
> This
> complements the longstanding ‘[`git remote add --track`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emaddem)’ option.
>
> The interface is based on the ‘git remote set-url’ subcommand.
>
> ```
> git remote set-branches base --add C
> git remote set-branches base A B D
> git remote set-branches base --delete D; # not implemented
> ```

So instead of the default glob [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) for the remote to track all branches under the `refs/remotes/<name>/` namespace, a [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) is updated to track only `<branch>`

```
git remote add -t main o2 https://github.com/git/git
```

Would give:

```
[remote "o2"]
        url = https://github.com/git/git
        fetch = +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/o2/main
```

Instead of:

```
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Adding a branch would be:

```
   git remote set-branches o2 --add master
[remote "o2"]
        url = https://github.com/git/git
        fetch = +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/o2/main
        fetch = +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/o2/master
```